# Run jQuery function after another function

Tags: jquery

The thing is, I am jquery.maskedinput plugin, which adds to the mask fields

works fine ...

but in a system that I am doing has a function to add extra fields, there the person clicks on a button that makes this feature and it adds more data fields, except that the error appears there, the date fields not added after the mask work, I tried to make the call after add the field but still did not work

I will demonstrate

I have the following fields in a form

```
<p class="data">
<input type="text" name="dataInicial" rel="data">
```

and I put the script

```
$ ('[rel=date]').mask("99/99/9999");
```

Works like a charm,

then I have another function that is called by the click of a button

that copies the html text field that I put above and add in a div

```
var field = $('p.data').html();

$('div.teste').append(field);
```

or on page two will look the same, and there lies the error, the mascara mask function only works on the page before it was not us that have been added ..

Comment: Share some of your code.

Comment: Try posting some actual code, or even better, set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: try to add your scenrario i can modify your non working function with same fiddle. strange reason to dislike answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the mask to the newly created field.

```
var field = $('p.data').html();
$(field).appendTo('div.teste').mask('99/99/9999');
```

Or maybe [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRyC8/) represent what you try to achieve.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, but he replaced what I filled in a void and added in the end I filled out before

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what behavior you try to achieve, but I'll add a fiddle that I think does the job.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use jquery live. As the field you have dynamically added will not have .maskedinput attached to it. Or you have to manually attach effect after addign field.